# typo3: does autoloader only work in root dir of an extension?

Tags: typo3, autoload

I know that I can put a file called ext_autoload.php in the *root directory* of my typo3 4.7 extension. This will load all classes mentioned in the ext_autoload.php file.

However, when I put an ext_autoload.php file in a *subdirectory* of a backend module, say `myext/mod1`
this file  ext_autoload.php seems to get ignored.

When I invoke the backend module by clicking on it in the left frame, `myext/mod1/index.php` is called, but the classes mentioned in the higher-level myext/ext_autoload.php also cannot be found.

Thus, only php files in the root directory of the extension seem to benefit from the autoloading mechanism.
**Is this correct behaviour?**

I have these entries in the error log.
(Assuming there aren't any misspellings of class names, of course...)

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'tx_myext_module1' not found in /var/www/typo3-4.7.8/typo3_src-4.7.8/t3lib/class.t3lib_div.php on line 4855, referer: http://.../cms/typo3/backend.php
```

I think it is inefficient to recursively scan the extension's subdirectories and look for autoloading files in many locations, but still, I didn' find more information on the autoloading mechanism.

This is what the file looks like:

```
return array(
    'tx_icdpdb_module1' => t3lib_extMgm::extPath('icdp_db', 'mod1/class.tx_icdpdb_module1.php')
);

?>
```

But ext/myextkey/index.php benefits from it, ext/myextkey/mod1/index.php does not.

I have solved the problem by good-old `include()`'ing the file containing the class I need.

Comment: How exactly does your autoload file look like?

Answer (score 1):

This work if you provide the "full" path to your files like stated in [the docs](http://wiki.typo3.org/Autoload):

```
<?php
$extensionPath = t3lib_extMgm::extPath('scheduler');
return array(
    'tx_scheduler_croncmd' => $extensionPath . 'class.tx_scheduler_croncmd.php',
    'tx_scheduler_croncmd_normalize' => $extensionPath . 'Normalize/class.tx_scheduler_croncmd_normalize.php',
);
?>
```

When you use `t3lib_extMgm::extPath()` or `t3lib_extMgm::extRelPath()`, everything should be fine.